# Pip install forced into global environment, when virtualenv is active

Tags: python, macos, pip

When trying (on a MacOS 10.8.5) to install packages into an activated virtual environment, pip fails with error:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install somepackage
...
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/somepackage': Permission denied
```

I've been using pip for a long without this issue. There are lots of similar questions and the answers suggest to use `sudo pip install ...`, however so far could not find a way to fix pip  so that packages go inside the virtual environment, instead of the global one.

Also, I've tried adding `--install-option="--prefix=env"`, but ran into other error. This is really unusual, haven't seen this issue in years of using pip.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using virtualenv, or the wrapper class?

Comment: Just virtualenv, not using wrapper

Comment: did you activate the virtualenv by using the source env/bin/activate ?

Comment: yes, just like I've showed in the example above, thanks.

Comment: does your terminal display (env) before your prompt?

Comment: It does, also `which python` and `which pip` point to the copy inside the virtualenv.

Comment: Just tried creating a new virtualenv, and pip works there properly... I will just rebuild it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer. I've ran:

```
deactivate
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install somepackage
```

That is created virtualenv right on top of the existing one - in the same directory and the problem was solved, even though I could not find an explanation.

Comment: The first time you created the virtualenv did you give it any options?